# Why can't I select some image files on some apps, while the Gallery app can?

Tags: applications, images, file-permissions

I have a Xiaomi device on Android 8.0 Oreo. I was editing some pictures in an application and sometimes the picture that I want to edit doesn't appear on the editing app, but there's in the gallery.

Why and how to fix this?

Comment: gallery requires media scanner for refresh which is sometimes buggy or only running on boot. media scanner excludes all directories containing .nomedia file. of course apps require storage permissions for this

Answer (score 0):

Photo app can find photos stored on device memory. It support some file extension like png, jpg. If file extension is not supported then it will not appear in photo apps.

You can update apps and also reset it.

Comment: The extension is jpg but it still can't appear

Comment: You can move that file to DCIM  folder then I think it will work. All photo app can read DCIM folder.